# What tools do I need to update an Excel spreadsheet with data from a website?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has fields that I need to update from a website keepa.com and I would like to know what kinds of tools/information I would need to code so that I could auto-update from the website itself as opposed to me copying and pasting.

I am looking for guidance not code so if any of you can share an example of you doing something like this and how you went about it, it would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately this question is probably too broad for this forum. Questions here at SO are usually geared towards "Here's some code I'm working on and I need it to do X but it's doing Y". Questions for guidance tend to go on and on with a lot of back and forth, which SO just isn't built to support. For some direction, I would search up "Web scraping with VBA" for plenty of examples of how people have pulled off similar stuff.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to invest the time into learning a more robust and better supported language like Python where people are actively developing libraries to help with thing like [interfacing with keepa.com](https://github.com/akaszynski/keepa). Python can also write data out to an excel file and all that too.